# использование OneHotEncoding с группировкой

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хочу привести их к такому виду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу это сделать?

Либо я делаю что-то не так, либо `onehotencoder` из sklearn тут не выручает.

DataSet:

```
d_test = {'id' : np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]), 
          'cat_feature': np.array([2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2])}
d_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

Comment: В смысле не выручает? Что конкретно не получается? Где код?

Comment: Я не могу с помощью него сделать так, чтобы айдишники стали уникальными

Comment: @josqa, можете привести пример данных в вопросе входные данные в виде текста (чтобы можно было скопировать)?

Comment: @MaxU d_test = {'id' : np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]),
          'cat_feature' : np.array([2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2])}
d_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [25]: pd.get_dummies(d_test, columns=["cat_feature"]).groupby("id", as_index=False).max()
Out[25]:
   id  cat_feature_1  cat_feature_2  cat_feature_3
0   1              0              1              0
1   2              1              0              1
2   3              1              0              0
3   4              1              1              1
4   5              0              1              0
```